# i need to connect to other ips from a php script runs at godaddy server

Tags: php, static-ip-address

i need to connect to other ips from a php script runs at godaddy server

connection  code :

```
$API = new routeros_api();              
$API->debug = false;
if($API->connect($result['mt_ip'], $result['mt_user'], $result['mt_pass'])){                                                                            
    $ARRAY = $API->comm("/system/resource/print");  
    $ram =  $ARRAY['0']['free-memory']/1048576;
    $hdd =  $ARRAY['0']['free-hdd-space']/1048576;                                              
}
```

routeros_api connect function :

```
function connect($ip, $login, $password)
{
    for ($ATTEMPT = 1; $ATTEMPT <= $this->attempts; $ATTEMPT++) {
        $this->connected = false;
        $this->debug('Connection attempt #' . $ATTEMPT . ' to ' . $ip . ':' . $this->port . '...');
        $this->socket = @fsockopen($ip, $this->port, $this->error_no, $this->error_str, $this->timeout);
        if ($this->socket) {
            socket_set_timeout($this->socket, $this->timeout);
            $this->write('/login');
            $RESPONSE = $this->read(false);
            if ($RESPONSE[0] == '!done') {
                $MATCHES = array();
                if (preg_match_all('/[^=]+/i', $RESPONSE[1], $MATCHES)) {
                    if ($MATCHES[0][0] == 'ret' && strlen($MATCHES[0][1]) == 32) {
                        $this->write('/login', false);
                        $this->write('=name=' . $login, false);
                        $this->write('=response=00' . md5(chr(0) . $password . pack('H*', $MATCHES[0][1])));
                        $RESPONSE = $this->read(false);
                        if ($RESPONSE[0] == '!done') {
                            $this->connected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($this->socket);
        }
        sleep($this->delay);
    }
    if ($this->connected){
        $this->debug('Connected...');           
    }else{
        $this->debug('Error...');           
    }
    return $this->connected;
}
```

i mean i am developing a php script on my website using which i want to connect to other IPs.i think godaddy is blocking this connection because it works fine at localhost

Comment: To start try first to read another webpage from your server (using curl or easier using file_get_contents. If that works, then set at home or search a server that is not in standard 80 port, to see at least if connection is blocked.

Comment: Btw, enable all the debug stuff and remove @ from @fsockopen so it echoes the possible errors.